# Writing Conditions for Inventory Type and Measurement on FileMaker

Tags: types, filemaker, inventory

How would I write this as a calculation in a specified field on FIleMaker Pro?

> Show Inventory::Type
>
> If Measurement 1 is
>
> between
>
> Inventory::Meas1Min
>
> &
>
> Inventory::Meas1Max

Generally it should look somewhere along the lines of this:

```
   Get (Inventory::Type)

If (Contacts::Measurement 1 is between Inventory::Meas1Min & Inventory::Meas1Max ) 



End If
```

Comment: This is impossible to understand. Please explain (1) which tables are involved and what is the relationship between them; (2) in which table is the calculation field; (3) which fields are the input to the calculation; (4) what is the expected result of the calculation (you cannot have `If()` without specifying a result to return when the test returns true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the formula would look something like this:

```
If ( 
Inventory::Meas1Min ≤ Contacts::Measurement 1 
and
Contacts::Measurement 1 ≤ Inventory::Meas1Max ; 
"OK" ; 
"Out of bounds" 
)
```

Note that related values will be taken from the **first** related record in the related table.

---

**Unrelated to your question, but important**:
Whenever you find yourself numbering your fields, e.g. `Measurement 1`, stop and revise your structure; it is almost certain you are violating normalization rules by using multiple *fields* where you should be using multiple *records* in another table.